# Java - How to get key and values from a string?

Tags: java

I have a **string**:

```
String responseFirst:
       {
        "1": "1930",
        "2": "ABC Partners",
        "3": "AB Part Mns NCA MS",
        "4": 18668800,
        "5": "6857.T",
        "6": "J1730413",
        "7": " Holy Ltd"
       }
```

From this response (stored in String), need to extract all keys and values separately.

**The only condition here is to not use JSON libraries, because the place where we want to use the solution, cannot use JSON libraries.**

Comment: If that is not JSON, what format is it? And how does it handle `"`quotes in the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this a try;

```
String[] stringArray =  responseFirst.split(",")
for(String kvPair: stringArray) {
String[] kv = kvPair.split(":");
String key = kv[0].substring(1).replace('"', '\u0020').trim();
String value = kv[1].substring(1, kv[1].length() - 1).replace('"', '\u0020').trim();

// Now do with key whatever you want with key and value...
if(key.equals("somekey")) {
   // Do something with value if the key is "somekey"...
}
}
```

Comment: don't forget to `trim` key and value.

Comment: Response for key print(comes with { in begining): 
 
{"1"
"2"
"3"
"4"
"5"
"6"
"7"

Comment: Fails if values have `,` or `:`

Comment: Please elaborate, in code for each key-value pair in String, 

key is storing in `String key`,

value is storing in `String value`

Comment: What if response to be parsed is `{ "1": "Foo, Bar: Baz" }`, i.e. with `,` and/or `:` in the value? Calling `split()` will fair on input like that.

Comment: @deepakmathpal what you actually want? this is working fine as per your question.

Comment: @Andreas you are right but I think we have to use JSON libraries to achieve this.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen In keys, { , this is also printing.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen You don't need a JSON *library*, just a JSON *parser*. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53809803/5221149).

Comment: @deepakmathpal here you go, I've updated the code. give the latest code a try.

Comment: @Andreas I think JSON parser is also prohibited in this question.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen Thanks. between, this is the output now, which exactly does not print the keys. First line is printing with "" and after that one comma " is missing.  :  "1"
2"
3"
4"
5"
6"
7"

Comment: @deepakmathpal now check, again updated the code.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen Close to perfect. Still, three things are there.

1.  While printing keys, one extra space is coming in the first line. (Because we remove {). If it will be aligned, it will be perfect.
2. Hardcoding in substring variable. 
3. same substring need to be applied with Values also. But there we need to remove the last one ({). So a proper logic with respect to index would be great.

Comment: @deepakmathpal code again updated: I think this is what you want. if yes, you can accept it. Thanks

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen Before accepting it, one last update need in code for values print--> Replace the extra character { in the end.

Values are: 

1939
Bay Pond Partners
BP Part Sht NCA MS
7559900
6457.T
J1730413
Glory Ltd }

Comment: @deepakmathpal check now

Answer (score 1):

> The only condition here is to not use JSON libraries

Since the input does *appear* to be JSON, **use a JSON parser**.

You could write your own, but all the JSON parsers out there are **open source**, so you can get the source and use the parser directly<sup>1</sup>, instead of writing your own from scratch.

That way you're not depending on a json *library*, but have your "own" code. Whether you actually modify that code, or use it as-is, is entirely up to you<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>*1) Make sure you don't violate any license agreements.*</sup>

Answer (score -1):

Use `.split()` from [(java.lang.String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

```
String[] kvPairs = "key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3".split(",");
```

This will give you an array kvPairs that contains these elements:

```
key1:value1
key2:value2
key3:value3
```

Now iterate over the KvPairs array and split then again to get the results :

```
for(String kvPair: kvPairs) {
   String[] kv = kvPair.split(":");
   String key = kv[0];
   String value = kv[1];

   // Now do with key whatever you want with key and value...
   if(key.equals("specialkey")) {
       // Do something with value if the key is "specialvalue"...
   }
}
```

Comment: Fails if values have `,` or `:`

Comment: System.out.println("keys are: " + key);  It comes with : { in the begining.
 
{"1"
"2"
"3"
"4"
"5"
"6"
"7"

Comment: @Andreas also in can contain escape symbols. Parsing of Json is not trivial.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Nashorn to do it. It's been available since Java 8.

```
String json = "{...}";
ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
Map m = (Map) engine.eval("(function(){ return " + json + " })()");
```

Comment: Nashorn is deprecated in Java 11 and will be gone soon ([JEP 335](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335)).